# Transportation Key (KEK)

Tags: rsa, public-key, elliptic-curves

I was studying about how to transport keys from one HSM environment to another and it came to me that I would need some sort of transportation key so the HSM keys would be  double encrypted.
How would this key be generated so it would be imported in both HSM securely? Coyld
It be used RSA or EC? Since the key could be generated in the target HSM and in the source we would just import the public key which is the responsible for encryption?

Comment: Usually smart card or multiple key parts. HSM's of a specific vendor may have ways of clustering them as well.